# Is there a comprehensive list of complexity theoretic reductions from and to prime number factorization?

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, prime-factorization, reference-works

I am interested in the complexity theoretic equivalences of prime number factorization.
I am especially interested to learn wether there are some not initially obvious reductions.
Im sure there is a lot known already on the subject but i am not sure where to find a good resource on this.

Is there a review article or even better a database that comprehensively lists all known reductions to and from prime number factorization?

Comment: I read a paper once (no idea how to find it now) that showed how solving the divisor function in polytime provides a way to solve factoring in polytime, even for numbers more composite than semiprimes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [Factoring Database](http://factordb.com/)? The [wiki](https://www.rieselprime.de/ziki/Factoring_Database) has plenty of information on how to use it if you have never used it before. I don't know of any other resource that you will find more useful for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! Its interesting, but seems more geared at actual factorization of say a given prime number. I was more thinking into the direction of complexity theoretic reductions though... Say a cook or turing reduction or anything that shows how factoring could be reduced to a related but distinct alternative problem... But +1!